# Changing the DNS Port on Windows 7

Tags: networking, dns

My ISP hijacks my DNS requests (or packets or whatever the heck is going on here), so I can't use my own DNS server. I don't necessarily *want* to use a different DNS server than the provided one from my ISP, but I'd like that option.

I found out when I got the error:

> Your router or ISP appears to be intercepting and redirecting all outgoing DNS requests

from namebench. So I ask you excuse my low knowledge on this topic. I researched it the best I could before coming here.

Currently I am using the default port (to the best of my knowledge that is port 53) but I cannot seem to find **any way** to change this. It is really starting to frustrate me.

Is there any way to do this? I heard you could change some registry entry but the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\DNS` does not exist on my machine. I did attempt to insert the value that was provided in this method

(`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\DNS\Parameters]
"SendOnNonDnsPort"=dword:000014e9`)

but when I restarted my DNS service the hijacking did not stop. So I am somewhat at a loss.

*Any* help is appreciated at this point.

Comment: Do you have antivirus on the PC? Try disabling it.

Comment: I did, that solved nothing. I also directly connected to the internet (usually use a router as a middleman. So I know it's not a router issue either.

Comment: I am still attempting to solve the issue. Currently I installed DNSCrypt but I am having several errors mainly with the UI.

Comment: This is randomuser12. This is the same e-mail but for some reason not the same account. I am a bit baffled but whatever. Now I can't comment, so this is just to say that MariusMatutiae's answer has solved my problem (I believe). I now show the country of origin for the DNS server being used and the hostname is `de.dnsmachine.net`

Comment: Thanks for trying to close the loop on your question. 1) You can comment within your thread, but only under the original account.  It looks like you created a new one instead of logging in to the old one.  See http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts to get your accounts merged. 2) Answers are reserved for solutions to the question.  This just refers to some unidentified or now missing post, so it's of no use to anyone else with a similar problem.  For an answer, post how you solved it (with credits).  If an answer here solved your problem, accept it (click checkmark), rather than comment.

Answer (score 1):

*Merging requires I log into the other account, something I can't do because this is the same exact e-mail I used to start it. If there is another one, it wouldn't matter because I don't know the password. Anyway, that means I still can't comment (need 50 rep). So this is just in regards to fixer1234's comment.*

Okay, here's how I solved it:

1. Install [DNSCrypt](https://dnscrypt.org/), preferably the Simple DNSCrypt as that's what I used and it is simply easier to deal with.
2. You need administrator privileges to install (I think) and use the program. Make sure the account you're on has them.
3. Install to the default directory. This will simply prevent problems, and is not strictly a requirement.
4. Run the program.
5. In the UI, a greyed object is disabled, and a semi-bright green object is enabled. Make sure to enable the DNS over your primary network card, and enable the primary DNS (the one you will be using). *Dual DNS support is not yet implemented so don't get frustrated if the secondary DNS won't enable dispute your best tries.*
6. Connect to your server of choice. *The original thread which got me to DNSCrypt as was provided by **MariusMatutiae** told me not to use OpenDNS or Cisco-based servers. This is possibly for security reasons so while not totally necessary it is probably better to listen than not.*
7. Change the settings to fit your desires. The default settings should work if all you're looking for is a workaround to a DNS hijacking problem.
8. You should be connected to DNSCrypt! While not strictly required, if using the Simple version leaving the UI up will keep you from forgetting the service is on or whatever.
9. To check the status of your DNS, go to [DNS Leak Test](https://www.dnsleaktest.com/), run the standard test, and see if the information matches, at least in part, your DNS settings. The hostname is your DNS host as far as I know.

*Please forgive me for any time I say "I think" or the like. I have some memory problems.*